# Update html list realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstorage

I am using jstorage to store local data and that is displayed on the html pages is there an javascript library that as soon as the local storage data changes it should automatically update the view?
I tied angular but couldn't find any example that I can follow.

Comment: You're looking for data binding, post what you have and people will take a look.

Comment: There is a listener for storage [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Comment: The localStorage won't change on its own. You will have to update its value, so there's no point watching for it to change. Whenever you update its value, trigger a view refresh. And did you say cou couldn't find any Angular example? Like, on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular, you can [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) for changes on `localStorage` and update your model according.

Something like this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($window, $scope, $window) {
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return $window.localStorage.data;
  }, function(n) {
    console.log('local storage changed');
    $scope.dataFromLS = n;
  });

  $scope.storeOnLS = function() {
    $window.localStorage.data = $scope.valueToStoreOnLS;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{dataFromLS}}<br />
  <input ng-model="valueToStoreOnLS" /><button ng-click="storeOnLS()">Save on LS</button>
</div>
```

[Working demo](http://output.jsbin.com/kexoqay)

Comment: And instead of watching for changes, what about triggering a view refresh whenever you update the localStorage? That would be one fewer watcher.

Comment: How do you trigger a view refresh in angular?

Comment: `$scope.apply()` if you need to, but the view should be refreshed automatically.

Comment: That's right. `the view should be refreshed automatically` after the `$watch` callback. I could add a service for localStorage and event driven layer so the controller will register to an event and the service will fire it when it change something in the localStorage but I really think that it's not  the context